# Neural Network Time Series Input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, time-series

All,
I am attempting to replicate the work done using Long Short Term Momory Artificial Neural Networks proposed in [this thesis](http://www.felixgers.de/papers/phd.pdf) by following [this (great) example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154720/recurrent-neural-network-in-11-1-explicit-examples/154762). I have a given dataset for which I train the neural network (an interpolating function `x[t]` output from NDSolve):

[image: datagraph]

I train:

```
* Create a Neural Network and correctly format the training data to \
predict the above time series *)

inputdata = Flatten@Table[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 200, 5500}];
trainingdata = 
  RandomSample[
   List /@ Most[#] -> List@Last[#] & /@ (Partition[inputdata, 51, 1])];
LSTMANN = 
 NetChain[{LongShortTermMemoryLayer[25], LinearLayer[1]}, 
  "Input" -> {50, 1}, "Output" -> 1]

trainedLSTMANN = NetTrain[LSTMANN, trainingdata]
```

Then I attempt to feed the data into the neural network. I want to give it 50 samples and have the ANN output one sample (the next predicted sample in time). I have been doing the following:

```
ListPlot[{Flatten@Table[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 200, 550}], 
  Flatten@NestList[Append[Rest[#], trainedLSTMANN[#]] &, 
     Table[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 49}], 350][[All, -1]]}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"True Values", "Predicted Values"}]
```

But I *think* I know this is wrong. This is me sending the initial values of `x[t]` into the ANN input and the output is the same each time, no? And I repeat is 350 times? I want to send a number of samples into the ANN, output the predicted value, then repeat but in a windowed fashion where the next number of samples is time shifted. I am **not** extremely proficient in Mathematica and have been unable to fully understand the syntax here (what does [[All, -1]] contribute? I know that it is indexing a vector but am confused at the purpose).

Any help is appreciated!